# Setter failing selectively in NSManagedObject

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, setter

I have a NSManagedObject which I'm trying to instantiate with given values. I access the setters like so:

```
object.couchID = (NSString *)[dictObject objectForKey:@"_id"];
```

...and this works fine on my machine, but my partner gets this error when he runs it on his machine:

```
'-[NSCFString type]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e465e0'
```

About 90% of the setters (all formatted in the same way) work on my partner's machine, but a good 10% fail with that error. All of them work on my machine.

We're running the exact same code (according to SVN (yes, I know)), and fetching the same data from the same server, so everything *seems* like it should work.

We've checked the objects being passed, and they're the same. Commenting out the setter allows the code to get through to the next troublesome setter, but of course we need it to actually work. How else should we troubleshoot? Thanks in advance.

---

Update 1: Unlocked the Tumbleweed badge for that one... guess it's too sticky to touch? Any thoughts or guesses are welcome. And hey, you could earn 50 points.*

---

Update 2: the mixed-good-news is that checking out a fresh version from source control results in the same problem on my machine, so a) it's definitely something in the code, and b) I can more actively troubleshoot. Thanks for all your suggestions so far, I'm going to go through them all again.

Comment: @Dan: For debug purposes, if you set object.couchID to a hardcoded string does it ever fail on your partners machine.... or same for the other NSManagedObject parameters?

Comment: @Damien Same problem with a hard-coded string.

Comment: @Dan you both run this code in simulator only? What Versions of XCode and SDK do you guys use?

Comment: Hard do tell without more code. It looks like a memory management issue. Also, have you defined a property called `-type` in one of your classes? In general, you should avoid giving properties names that already exist in other classes with a different type, especially in Core Data.

Comment: @Nick Yes, both running in simulator using latest XCode (4.0.2) and iOS SDK 4.3.

Comment: @Bavarious None of the Core Data classes have a `type` property. That's part of the JSON response though to determine what class the JSON object maps to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into something similar at work the other day. I suspect that one of you has a stale .momd file inside the app bundle, and that it's not being replaced when it gets upgraded. I suspect this is a bug in Xcode 4, though I haven't totally verified it yet. If your partner deletes the app completely and *then* installs the app, does the error go away?

Comment: Meaning—if he deletes the compiled binaries, or if he checks out an entirely fresh copy from source control?

Comment: Delete the compiled binaries. Your question is tagged with iphone, so I assume you're running this either in a simulator or on the device. Delete it out of the simulator or the device completely, then install it again.

Comment: Hm, unfortunately that didn't do it. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Alright, as it turns out that *was* it. An unrelated data model issue threw us off the trail for a bit, but it actually was the stale build folder that threw a spanner in the works.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create a temporary variable whose value is `object` cast to whatever the actual class is, e.g.

```
MyClass *c = (MyClass *)object; // if object is in fact a MyClass instance
c.couchID = (NSString *)[dictObject objectForKey:@"_id"];
```

I have seen cases where the compiler cannot make mental leap and realize that your attribute is the class you know it is. The solution for me in these cases has been to be more explicit. Does this make sense? It's worth a shot at least, no? :-)

Comment: Thanks, Mark—makes sense and I'll give it a try when we reconvene on the project tomorrow.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't make a difference... problem persists.

Comment: Interesting. Is it possible that `dictObject` does not have a value for key `_id`? Could the machine on which this code is failing be accessing a different data source than the data source you access on your machine? Could the data not be what you think it is, causing `objectForKey` to return nil or something you are not expecting? What's the debugger tell you?

Comment: Hm. DictObject definitely has the _id (checked in source and doublechecked in debugger). And it's the same (remote) data source.

Answer (score 0):

if this code fails on your partner's machine:

```
someManagedObject.couchID = @"some hardcoded string";
```

seems like you have a dangling pointer: i would check that someManagedObject is properly retained and still a valid object when you try to call the -setCouchID method on it.

Comment: That can't be it, because the assignments that fail are in series with a variety of other assignments (identically formatted) that succeed, on the same object. And there's nothing custom about the object: it's out-of-the-box from the xcdatamodel

Comment: I should say: I *don't think* that can be it, because... :)

Answer (score 0):

I have had nearly the same problem when trying to draw a CATiledLayer with data in NSManagedObjects. What should be a valid object barfs with an "unrecognised selector" exception

It nearly always happens because theres no retain on the object external to the point where you are trying to set or get the property. Being in a separate thread seemed to have a relationship too.

After fruitlessly trying to get round this with [NSManagedObjectContext lock] and retain on the context within the new thread I eventually just threw the contents of my fetch into a mutable set to try and keep a grip on it which seems to work on iOS but not on OS X so well.

So a couple of possibilities

- Are you doing this not in the main
  thread and does the MOC have a retain
  within that thread. Check the docs
  for [NSManagedObjectContext lock]. But essentially each thread working with the context needs its own retain on the context.
- Try throwing it into a container
  while you operate on it. Make it a
  bit stickier. Sorry if that sounds
  like voodoo but it is.

Comment: Hm, I'm not doing actively anything with threading: everything happens on the main thread, and sandwiched between other operations (on the same object) that work.